# What does type after the = do in a type declaration

Tags: delphi

In mORMot's SynCommons.pas there is the following snippet of code:

```
type
  ....
  TTimeLog = type Int64;
             ^^^^
```

What is the purpose of the second `type` keyword (in front of `Int64`)?

Comment: That is described in [`this topic`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Declaring_Types).

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 10):

From [Data Types, Variables, and Constants Index (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Types)

> When you declare a type that is identical to an existing type, the
>   compiler treats the new type identifier as an alias for the old one.
>   Thus, given the declarations:
>
> ```
> type TValue = Real;
> var
>   X: Real;
>   Y: TValue;
> ```
>
> X and Y are of the same type; at runtime, there is no way to
>   distinguish TValue from Real. This is usually of little consequence,
>   but if your purpose in defining a new type is to utilize runtime type
>   information, for example, to associate a property editor with
>   properties of a particular type - the distinction between 'different
>   name' and 'different type' becomes important. In this case, use the
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> type newTypeName = type KnownType
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> type TValue = type Real;
> ```
>
> forces the compiler to create a new, distinct type called TValue.
>
> For var parameters, types of formal and actual must be identical. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> type
>   TMyType = type Integer;
> procedure p(var t:TMyType);
>   begin
>   end;
>
> procedure x;
> var
>   m: TMyType;
>   i: Integer;
> begin
>   p(m); // Works
>   p(i); // Error! Types of formal and actual must be identical.
> end;
> ```

Comment: Aha, it enables RTTI to see the types apart, that explains it.

Comment: There's a lot more to this than RTTI. It influences type identity too. That's a compile time property.